# Change URL from Href with Dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have multiple Dropdowns on my Site to Change the URL via Dropdown.
But the Problem is, that the first Dropdown changes the also the Value of the second HREF. How can I fix this? With the each Functions nothing changes..

```js
$(function() {
    $('.container').each(function(){
        var getUrl = $(".application :selected").val();
        $('.link_combo').attr("href", getUrl);

        $(".application").change(function () {
          console.log(this.value);
          $(".link_combo").attr('href', this.value);
  
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<select class="application selectpicker">
 <option value="fileadmin/user_upload/9_downloads/KomPass-Threading_DE.pdf">Deutsch</option>
 <option value="fileadmin/user_upload/9_downloads/KomPass-Threading_GB.pdf">Englisch</option>
 <option value="fileadmin/user_upload/9_downloads/KomPass-Threading_FR.pdf">Französisch</option>
 <option value="fileadmin/user_upload/9_downloads/KomPass-Threading_IT.pdf">Italienisch</option>
</select>
<p><a class="link_combo" href="#" download><i class="icon-file-pdf"></i>Download als PDF</a></p>
</div>

<div class="container">
<select class="application selectpicker">
 <option value="fileadmin/user_upload/9_downloads/SECOND_1.pdf">Deutsch</option>
 <option value="fileadmin/user_upload/9_downloads/SECOND_2.pdf">Englisch</option>
 <option value="fileadmin/user_upload/9_downloads/SECOND_3.pdf">Französisch</option>
 <option value="fileadmin/user_upload/9_downloads/SECOND_4.pdf">Italienisch</option>
</select>
<p><a class="link_combo" href="#" download><i class="icon-file-pdf"></i>Download als PDF</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
$('.link_combo')
```

will find *all* elements with class `.link_combo`.  In your code, there are *two* anchor elements with this class, so both are changed.

You need to limit the scope of the selector so it only finds the relevant link, eg:

```
$(function() {
    $('.container').each(function(){
        var container = this;
        var getUrl = $(".application :selected", container).val();
        $('.link_combo', container).attr("href", getUrl);

        $(".application", container).change(function () {
          console.log(this.value);
          $(".link_combo", container).attr('href', this.value);
        });
    });
});
```

there are other ways and your original `$(".application").change` was also being called twice (I also added container to this above) - so you could move the event handler out of the `.each`, eg

```
$(function() {
    $('.container').each(function(){
        var container = this;
        var getUrl = $(".application :selected").val();
        $('.link_combo', container).attr("href", getUrl);
    });

    $(".application").change(function () {
      console.log(this.value);
      $(this)
          .closest(".container")
          .find(".link_combo")
          .attr('href', this.value);
    });
});
```

Edit: Add container context to getUrl line

Comment: thanks. but when load the page first, the links are the same. after i select one then the href's has the right value..

Comment: Then what exactly is the problem?   You said the hrefs get the wrong value ("first Dropdown changes the also the Value of the second HREF"), then that they get the right value ("the href's has the right value").  So what's the issue?

Comment: your script works perfect! when i load the site, the href of boths links get the same url. but thats wrong. when i load the page or change the dropdown the script should do the same.
http://jsfiddle.net/herrsaidy/vsrkn1k0/1/

Comment: You're just missing the context on the getUrl:  `var getUrl = $(".application :selected", container).val();` http://jsfiddle.net/vsrkn1k0/2/